# video not uploading from android to server in PHP using retrofit

Tags: php, android, mysql, retrofit2

I am trying to upload a video from android to server and my db using Xampp, However when I try to upload, neither the video is being uploaded nor I am getting an error .Even the video url is being uploaded. I am using retrofit to upload.

```
if (!videoPath.isEmpty()) {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(Constants.ROOT_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();


                File file = new File(videoPath);

                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), file);


                MultipartBody.Part video = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("vid", file.getName(), requestBody);

                RequestBody requestEmail = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), userEmail);

                MultipartBody.Part email = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("email", userEmail, requestEmail);

                String todayDate = postFormatDate(new Date());
                RequestBody requestDate = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), todayDate);

                MultipartBody.Part date = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("today_date", todayDate, requestDate);

                RetrofitApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitApi.class);
                Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadVideo(video, email, date);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, getString(R.string.server_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                });

            }
```

My retrofit interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("post_video.php")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadVideo(@Part MultipartBody.Part video, @Part MultipartBody.Part email, @Part MultipartBody.Part today_date);
```

and my php code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['vid']['name'])) {

$path = 'Images/';

$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

$url = 'http://' . $server_ip .'/folder/' . $path;

$con3 = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);

$extension3 = pathinfo($_FILES['vid']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$file_url = $url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension3;
$file_path = $path . getFileName() . '.' . $extension3;


try {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['vid']['tmp_name'], $file_path);

    $date = $_FILES['today_date']['name'];

    $sql3 ="INSERT INTO posts_media_files (url, post_id,date) VALUES ('$file_url','$id_bind','$date');";
    $stm3 = $con3->prepare($sql3);

    $stm3->execute();

}

}
```

My xampp upload file limit is 200mb(I did increase it). Please help me, I'm really stucked!.

Comment: What response did you get in Retrofit? Success or failure? Please [edit] the question and post the response here (if failure post stack trace). If you don't get any response in Retrofit, please click on `Logs` button in XAMPP and select `error.log`. This will open PHP/Apache error log in notepad. Scroll till the end to find the latest log. If possible, post it as well (not full log only the latest one).

Comment: Just a note: `$con3->prepare($sql3)`...what is the point of using a prepared statement if you don't parameterise yor query? I suggest you check [how to write your queries correctly and safely](http://bobby-tables.com/php) using parameters. It'll also help you avoid some basic syntax errors, as a bonus.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I fixed my issue, by increasing my xampp max upload file, max_file_size, and POST max size. And refreshing my xampp